# Jenkins capturing outputed messages

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins pipeline where I have some stages implemented.
Jenkins outputs some messages while the job is running.

Code:

```
stage('My stage') {
  options {
    timeout(time: 2, unit: "MINUTES")
  }
  steps {
    script {
       ./script.sh
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
...
20:12:40  Timeout set to expire in 2 min 0 sec
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
20:12:40  ./script.sh                   '                  
20:14:40  Cancelling nested steps due to timeout
20:14:40  Sending interrupt signal to process
20:14:48  ...
20:14:48  + JOB_NAME=...
20:14:48  + BUILD_URL=...
20:14:48  + BUILD_ID=567
20:14:48  + BUILD_RESULT=SUCCESS
```

In this example I am in the middle of a job and I have lots of messages been displayed. I need to capture this message "Cancelling nested steps due to timeout".
When jenkins outputs this message I want to be able to send notifications to a user.

I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

After executing the `script.sh` you can check the console log like below.

```
stage('My stage') {
  options {
    timeout(time: 2, unit: "MINUTES")
  }
  steps {
    script {
       sh "./script.sh"
       
       // Checking the console log
       def consoleLog = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME).getBuildByNumber(Integer.parseInt(env.BUILD_NUMBER)).logFile.text
       if(consoleLog.contains("Cancelling nested steps due to timeout")) {
                 echo "Send the Notification"
         }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also if you don't want to do this sequentially, you can create a parallel stage and keep on checking the logs.

Comment: Looks good. :) How can I make this to notificate users except when status is aborted?

Comment: You can either use Email Ext: https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/ plugin to send an Email or a plugin like Slack Notification: https://plugins.jenkins.io/slack/. Once you Abort the execution will abort hence this step will not be executed..

Comment: Without plugin. Using code

Comment: How exactly you want to notify users?

Comment: I have a script for it. Basically I just want to detect when this job gets aborted (inside this existent code). Anyway to detect status aborted inside the code?

Comment: When you say abort, who is aborting the Job? Do you mean someone manually killing the job?

Comment: If the job gets aborted due to a timeout for example.

Comment: I tried this code and I am getthing this message: "Scripts not permitted to use method hudson.model.Job getBuildByNumber int. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature."

Comment: Go to JENKINS_URL/scriptApproval/ and approve the script.

Comment: Any other way to do this without approving the script? As I am not Jenkins admin

Comment: One alternative is, you can get the console output by calling `JENKINS_URL/job/$JOB_NAME/$BUILD_NUMBER/consoleText` You can use something like `curl` or `HTTP Request Plugin` for this and then check whether your message is there.

Comment: Do you think you could provide an answer with code for this please?